# When to close the result set (Basic ODBC question)

Tags: sql, iis, asp-classic, odbc, resultset

I am working on some small project for the local firm and the following code runs fine on my machine, but it produces errors on their server. Currently I don't have access to that server, and this is not a field that I know a lot about, so I have to ask you guys.

The page is written in the classic ASP (javascript for scripting).
The logic goes like this:

```
conn.Open("myconnection");
bigQuery = "...";
rs = conn.execute(bigQuery);
while (!rs.eof) {
    ...
    smallQuery = "..."
    rssmall = conn.execute(smallQuery);
    ...
    rssmall.close();
    ...
    rs.movenext();
}
rs.close();
conn.close();
```

As I said this runs fine on my machine, but it returns some error (the worst thing is that I don't even know what error) on company's server **if bigQuery returns more than ~20 rows**. Is there something wrong with my code (this really isn't my field, but I guess it is ok to gather data in the loop like this?), or is there something wrong with their IIS server.

Thanks.

edit:
More info:
It 's Access database. Everything is pretty standard:

```
conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
conn.Open("D:/db/testingDb.mdb");
```

Queries are bit long, so I wont post them. They are totally ordinary selects so they aren't the issue.

Comment: Your basic logic looks fine, and the fact that it executes on your local machine hints that it might be a configuration issue on the client machine but more information would be helpful.  What database are you using?  What does your connection string look like?  What do the SELECT statements look like?  And they're going to have to tell you what the error message is!  (Many clients do not realize that software developers do *not* read minds remotely ;-).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I only needed a confirmation that basic logic is fine. I updated the question, but I am almost sure that they managed to spill the coffee on the server or something like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a legacy Classic ASP application which I inherited that was very similar (big queries with other queries running within the loop retrieving the first query's results) that ran fine until forty or more records were returned. The way I "solved" the problem was to instantiate another connection object to run the other query. So using your pseudo code, try --

```
conn.Open("myconnection");
conn2.Open("myconnection")

bigQuery = "...";
rs = conn.execute(bigQuery);
while (!rs.eof) {
    ...
    smallQuery = "..."
    rssmall = conn2.execute(smallQuery);
    ...
    rssmall.close();
    ...
    rs.movenext();
}
rs.close();
conn2.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: Yep, that solved the problem. Strange. Does anyone know why is this happening? Is that the case with every ADODB connection, or only with classic ASP? Thank you very much. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

What server are they actually running?

Most newer versions of Windows Server don't actually come with the Jet 4.0 driver for 64 bit at all so you can't use an access database with that driver if your app runs as a 64 bit app.  You can try running as 32 bit which might solve the problem.

There is an [alternative driver](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en) packaged as an office component which may be an option.

Try writing a simple test page that literally opens and closes the database connection like so:

```
<%
Dim conn
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open("D:/db/testingDb.mdb")

Response.Write("Database Opened OK")

conn.Close()

%>
```

Run this on the production server and if you see `Database Opened OK` then you'll know it's definitely the query rather than the database causing the issue.

If you get an error trying to open the database then you need to changed to using the newer driver or try the app in 32 bit mode

In the case that it is the query causing the issue then it may be that you'll need to use the various additional arguments to the `Open()` method to try using a different cursor (forward only if you only need to iterate over the results once) which will change how ADODB retrieves the data and hopefully mediate any performance bottleneck related to the query.

**Edit**

If you want to try debugging the code a bit more add the following at the start of the file.  This causes the ASP script processor to continue even if it hits an error

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Then at intervals throughout the file where you expect an error might have happened do

```
If Err <> 0 Then
    Response.Write(Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
End If
```

See [this](http://asp101.com/samples/error.asp) article from ASP 101 for the basics of error handling in ASP and VBScript

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Opening connection is not the problem. As I said in my question, everything runs OK until there is more than 20 entries in the database. I am not sure what kind of the error is related to the number of the returned entries of a query? I know it is very confusing question because I can't even provide error description. I will go there tomorrow and tell you guys more about the problem if it still exist (I guess that one restart of the IIS will do the job :))

Comment: @Klark: Ctrl-Alt-Del is often a good first thing to try when debugging problems like this.

Comment: Added some code you can add to get hopefully meaningful error messages out of your code